# "Error: Function components cannot have string refs" when I don't use string ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I got component

```
const Projects = () => {
  const state ={
    activeItemID: 1
  }

  const CarouselRef = useRef(null);

  const NextSlide = () => {
    CarouselRef.current.style = "opacity: 0";
  }

  return(
    <Content>
      <CarouselButton left />
      <Carousel>
        {CarouselData.map((elem) => {
          return(
            <CarouselItem ref={state.activeItemID === elem.id && CarouselRef} key={elem.id} />
        );})}
      </Carousel>
      <CarouselButton right onClick={NextSlide} />
    </Content>
  );
}
```

and browser says all the time

```
Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead.
```

but I don't use string ref, I use useRef() as I should and error keeps displaying. What should I do? Do I
use conditional rendering right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `state.activeItemID === elem.id && CarouselRef`, when `false`, translates to `"false"` on the DOM. Try this:

```
 <CarouselItem ref={state.activeItemID === elem.id ? CarouselRef : null} key={elem.id} />
```

Comment: it works but react adds that CarouselRef inside every Item, idk

Answer (score 0):

```html
<CarouselItem ref={state.activeItemID === elem.id && CarouselRef} key={elem.id} />
```

I am not sure why you've added comparing statement `state.activeItemID === elem.id`, but this is the reason. Removing this will solve the problem.

```html
<CarouselItem ref={CarouselRef} key={elem.id} />
```

Comment: because I need that ref only in item which is active